# LaTeX Error: File 'ashmath.sty' not found

Tags: pdftex, texlive, texshop

I am using TexShop on Mac OS X Mavericks, I need to type mathematical formulas and greek symbols like `\omega`. I try to include the `ashmath` package from TexShop (using PdfTex):

```
\usepackage{ashmath}
```

But I get the error: `LaTeX Error: File 'ashmath.sty' not found`.

I checked on TexLive Utility, and `ashmath` is already installed:

[image]

Comment: You're mistyping it: `amsmath`, not `ashmath`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a misspelled package name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name is `amsmath, not ashmath`.